# PHP order array by date

Tags: php

There are some sets of arrays I need to order by date, here is an example of the array.

```
[0]=>
  array(10) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["title"]=>
      string(123) "Text"
      ["date"]=>
      string(25) "17 November 2013, 8:09 am"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["title"]=>
      string(257) "Text"
      ["date"]=>
      string(26) "15 November 2013, 10:26 pm"
    ...

[1]=>
  array(10) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["title"]=>
      string(123) "Text"
      ["date"]=>
      string(25) "16 November 2013, 8:09 am"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["title"]=>
      string(257) "Text"
      ["date"]=>
      string(26) "10 November 2013, 10:26 pm"
    ...
```

I used this function to arrange the array by date but that is not working

```
function sortFunction( $a, $b ) {
    return strtotime($a["date"]) - strtotime($b["date"]);
}
```

It arrange the inner most array by date,but i want to arrange all the elements in the data-set not just the innermost array, any idea how to fix this?

**Update**

The output should look like this,

```
[0] =>
array(2) {
["title"]=>
      string(123) "Text"
      ["date"]=>
      string(25) "17 November 2013, 8:09 am"
}
[1] =>
array(2) {
 string(123) "Text"
      ["date"]=>
      string(25) "16 November 2013, 8:09 am"
}
[3] =>
array(2) {
 string(123) "Text"
      ["date"]=>
      string(25) "15 November 2013, 8:09 am"
}
```

etc

Comment: Give an example of how the resulting array should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd merge your arrays into one parent array. Sounds like your sort function is working on the inner arrays, so you should be able to sort them all then:

```
<?php

$new_array = array();

foreach($parent_array as $children) {
    foreach($children as $grand_children) {
        $new_array[] = $grand_children;
    }
}

$parent_array = sortFunction($new_array);
unset($new_array);

print_r($parent_array); // now contains all (grand) children in one top level array

?>
```